# Turning Computer into Router,Network Address Translation encryption.?

Tags: encryption, router, ethernet, nat

I have windows seven and am using connectify. but when i try to connect to the interner through my ethernet court in my dorm room the comp0uter doesnt recognize the ethernet cord. I belive that the below paragraph from connectify's support page explains this.

A hotel, a college, or a business that wants to prevent add-on routers can buy commercial routers that do this kind of "deep packet inspection", and can be programmed to "bump" your connection if they see this happening. The only way to prevent this is to hide the fact you're doing any routing. That's technically possible by encrypting data leaving the NAT. Connectify doesn't have this as option, presently. And the problem with this solution is that the information in that packet would also be useless until it's decrypted.

http://support.connectify.me/entries/21114388-when-my-hotspot-starts-my-connection-is-still-enabled-but-loses-the-internet

My question is, how can i avoid getting bumped. is there away to encrypt the DATA going out of the NAT? or maybe a similar program to connectify that does it for me.